# Prove $f\in L_p$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1f_nhdm=\int_0^1fhdm$, prove $f\in L^p(m)$ , where $1\le p&amp;lt;\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241076/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-int-01f-nhdm-int-01fhdm-prove-f-in-lpm-w)

Can anyone help with this question?

When ${f_n}$ is defined on [0,1], $ ||f_n||_p\le1$, $1<p<\infty$,
$f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, $m$ is Lebesgue measure, and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1f_ng \, dm=\int_0^1fg \, dm,$$ for any $g\in L^{\infty}(m)$.

Prove $f\in L_p$

Comment: This (essentially unanswered) question is exactly the same -- except that the case $p =1$ is allowed in the other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/241076/

Answer (score 0):

Since $L^\infty[0,1]$ is dense in $L^q[0,1]$,
$$
\|f\|_p=\sup\{\int_0^1fg\,dm: \|g\|_q=1\}=\sup\{\int_0^1fg\,dm: g\in L^\infty[0,1]\mbox{ and }\|g\|_q=1\}.
$$
Note that, for $g\in L^\infty$ with $\|g\|_q=1$,
$$
\left|\int_0^1fg\,dm\right|=\lim\,\left|\int_0^1f_ng\,dm\right|\leq \|f_n\|_p\,\|g\|_q\leq1.
$$
So $\|f\|_p\leq1$.